# Allow all websites for administrator account and block all websites (but a few) for limited accounts

Tags: windows-xp, administrator, blocking, hosts, ipsec

At my work we have a PC which runs Windows XP and is used by all employees. This PC is mainly used for our company website: a trailer booking website. At the moment there is one account: an administrator account. So everybody can do everything and go to websites like Facebook. That's something I would like to block.

Is there a possibility in Windows to block all websites but a few for the limited worker account and allow all websites for the administrator account? I tried a few options, under which changing the hosts file and using IPSec to block all websites but our company site, but these methods aren't user account specific.

We only have one PC at our company and two wireless routers, no proxy's or anything.

Comment: Do they even need to use the computer?

Answer (score 1):

Check out group policy. You aren't running a domain(doesn't sound like it anyway), so any changes would only apply to that computer. GPO allows you to specify, per user, what they can and cannot do. 
Normally you would do this from your internet gateway, but it sounds like your infrastructure is still very small so you may not have the means to do this. GPO certianly isn't the best soultion, but it's free and you already have it.

http://www.grouppolicy.biz/2010/07/how-to-use-group-policy-to-allow-or-block-urls/